# Django 1.5.1 python 3.3.1 on Windows 7

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I am not able to start django project without preceding it with full path python executable and the full path of django_admin.py

Python\Scripts folder is in Environment path. Python exe is in environment path.

But as the tutorial suggests, I cannot start a project with "django.admin.py startproject "

Instead i have to type "C:\Python33\python.exe C:\Python33\Scripts\django-admin.py startproject "

Is there a way to get around this. Any reason why this happens will be of help

The %PATH% value is:

C:\Python33\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ActiveState Komodo Edit 8\;C:\Perl64\site\bin;C:\Perl64\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files\ThinkPad\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\ThinkPad\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Ulead Systems\MPEG;C:\Program Files (x86)\Symantec\VIP Access Client\;C:\Perl64\bin;C:\Python33\Scripts;C:\RailsInstaller\Git\cmd;C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\bin

Thanks!
Akash.

Comment: Can you paste the PATH value?

Comment: Can you check that ``django-admin.py`` is in the ``C:\Python33\Scripts`` directory?

Comment: have you restarted the shell(cmd)?

Comment: Did it use to work? Has installing something else recently broken everything? You also need to check that *.py files are associated with python.exe, that could have changed.

Comment: Is Python correctly associated with '.py' files? What error do you receive when running the django admin command explicitly without specifying the Python interpreter first?

Comment: No, I just installed DJANGO.. Like I said, it is working for me to learn django, since I am using full path and preceding it with python executable.

Comment: When I run it without full path and the the python.exe it just displays the help command of django as if no arguments were passed at all